# Swift 3.0 - Couldn't Send "plus" (+) to mySQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, swift3

I would like to sent something to mysql using php, however, swift seem failed to sent the information I want, and I traced the problem using php, and finally I found that its the symbol "+" that causing the problem, how am I gonna solve the problem? Is it because swift utf8 encoding problem? Please advise.

```
func LoadDataToServer(){
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:"<myphpaddress>.php")! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let poststring = "tag=newcustomer&ap_contact_no=+12345678&cpm_no=123331231"

request.httpBody = poststring.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

    if (error != nil)
    {
        print("error =\(error)")
        return
    }
    else
    {
        print("response\(response)")
        let responsestring = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(responsestring ?? "error")
    }
}
task.resume()
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` is one of the reserved character in URLs, just like `?`, `&`, `=`, and so on. It is an equivalent of a space character. If you need to have a plus sign in the URL, you need to encode it to `%2B`.

Read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding